# Problem while adding Journal Entry with customer in Quickbook - Message: Passed array has no key for 'Value' when contructing an ReferenceType

Tags: php, quickbooks

I go through this documentation "https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/journalentry"

And tried to add journal entry with line having customer as shown in the below code:

```
$journal_entry_create['TxnDate'] = date('Y-m-d');
$journal_entry_line = array(
                        'Amount' => $amount,
                        'DetailType' => 'JournalEntryLineDetail',


                        'JournalEntryLineDetail' => array(
                            'PostingType' => Credit,
                            'Entity' => array(
                                'Type' => 'Customer',
                                'EntityRef' => array(
                                    'type' => 'Customer',
                                    'value' => "2",
                                    'name' => 'Abc'
                                )
                            ),
                            'AccountRef' => array(
                                'name' => 'Account Name',
                                'value' => '1'
                                ),

                        )
                    );
$journal_entry_lines[] = $journal_entry_line;
$journal_entry_create['Line'] = $journal_entry_lines;
$journal_entry_receipt_create = QBJournalEntry::create($journal_entry_create);
$journal_entry_receipt_create_result = $dataService->Add($journal_entry_receipt_create);
```

Without EntityRef its working fine but when I add EntityRef its giving me error "Message: Passed array has no key for 'Value' when contructing an ReferenceType"

Answer (score 2):

Only just came across this problem myself. They did fix this issue but didn't seem to document it at all or tell anyone. Found the fix in the [source code](https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK/commit/797d1a2dc2685b4f103e938c5d4f43da46af33ae). You need to use "JournalEntryEntity" instead of "Entity" under "JournalEntryLineDetail", like so:

```
'JournalEntryLineDetail' => array(
                            'PostingType' => "Credit",
                            'JournalEntryEntity' => array(
                                'Type' => 'Customer',
                                'EntityRef' => array(
                                    'value' => "2"
                                )
                            ),
                            'AccountRef' => array(
                                'name' => 'Account Name',
                                'value' => '1'
                                ),
                            )
```

Also I used the FacadeHelper from the V3 of the PHP SDK (I'm not sure if it'll work with the method you were using):

```
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\FacadeHelper;

...

$journal_entry_receipt_create = FacadeHelper::reflectArrayToObject('JournalEntry', $journal_entry_create);
$journal_entry_receipt_create_result = $dataService->Add($journal_entry_receipt_create);
```

I know this is probably too late for you OP but hopefully it helps someone else!